# How to create atlas for SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, texture-atlas

How to create atlas for SpriteKit ?
I tried to transfer all my images to some folder and give it extension. At result folder will called "somefolder.atlas" . Is it right way to use it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds correct. Make sure you also enable atlas generation in Xcode settings (check out the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-texture_atlas/Recipe.html) about this, with step-by-step pictures).

Then, supposing your atlas folder is named "somefolder.atlas" and it contains a file "1.png", you would do something like this:

```
SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"somefolder"];
SKTexture *texture = [atlas textureNamed:@"1"];
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteWithTexture:texture];
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :) Also I see that to enable texture atlas generation I need to have at least one .atlas in my project, otherwise this option is invisible