# how to create atlas files for Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, sktextureatlas

I've just been toying with SpriteKit, and Ive noticed that the Apple examples use SpriteKit with "atlas" extensions. As they don't use them in Xcode, what I've dome is use |"Asset files"| and renamed them to ".atlas"

Is this the correct way to go about this or am I missing a few templates?

Also, on top of that, is there a way I can bundle the sound files (I don't care what format as I can re-encode them) so that they are also formatted into a single archive?

Comment: No. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-texture_atlas/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013290-CH1-SW1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970781/how-to-create-atlas-for-spritekit

Comment: Consolidate sounds into a singleton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697478/skaction-playsoundfilenamed-from-singleton

Comment: Thanks @LearnCocos2D, that was precisely what I was looking for! can you rather post it as an answer so I can up it unless its a previous?

Comment: Ah right... Thanks.. Works now!!! Cheers!